# How to stream a video file using VLC?

Tags: video-streaming, vlc

I have tried using this guide
http://www.howtogeek.com/118075/how-to-stream-videos-and-music-over-the-network-using-vlc/
to stream a video file over UDP.

I have managed to set up a stream, and capture it from another VLC instance.

However, what was streamed was MY ENTIRE DESKTOP, and not only the file.

How do I ONLY STREAM THE FILE?

Thanks.

Comment: Today i tried again to stream, but when i press the stream button, nothing happens... No error message. I configured everything i could think of. What could have caused this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you set your 'Capture Device' to 'Desktop'.